# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'movie_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Tags: mysql

```
   SELECT DISTINCT actor_id 
    FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT actor_id
      FROM cast 
      WHERE NOT movie_id in 
            (SELECT movie_id 
            FROM cast 
            INNER JOIN actors 
            ON actors.ID = cast.actor_id 
            WHERE full_name = 'Kevin Bacon')) as A
     WHERE movie_id in 
     (SELECT movie_id  
     FROM cast 
     WHERE actor_id in
        (SELECT DISTINCT actor_id 
        FROM cast 
        WHERE movie_id in 
            (SELECT movie_id  
            FROM cast 
            INNER JOIN actors 
            ON actors.ID = cast.actor_id 
            WHERE full_name = 'Kevin Bacon')))
   AND actor_id <> (SELECT id from actors
   where full_name = "Kevin Bacon")
;
```

I keep getting this error of Unknown column 'movie_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'; which i do not understand, as the blocks of this code taken separately work just fine.

What am I missing here?

Thks!

Comment: Which subquery causes the error? Remember that you are also reusing the same tables so the field values are confused. Give aliases to your tables when you use them. Ex: `Select c.movie_id from cast c;` C is the alias.

Comment: Do tell what you are trying to achieve?  I'm sure the query can be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I see and error on this simplified example of your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor_id
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT actor_id FROM ...) as A
WHERE movie_id in (...);
```

On the WHERE clause you are referencing "movie_id" from "A" table, but in the inner query "( SELECT DISTINCT actor_id FROM ...)" this column is not selected.

Also, there are so much anidated queries, i'm sure this can be simplified if you give an example "with words" of what you want to get.

**Response to the commented goal**

I did not found an easy answer for your goal, but i will go this way:

First, i will create a view with actors relationship based on the movies they acted...

```
CREATE VIEW vw_relations AS (
    SELECT
        c1.actor_id AS actor1_id, a1.full_name AS actor1_fullname,
        c1.movie_id, m.title AS movie_title,
        c2.actor_id AS actor2_id, a2.full_name AS actor2_fullname
    FROM
        cast AS c1
    INNER JOIN
        cast AS c2 ON c2.movie_id = c1.movie_id AND c2.actor_id != c1.actor_id
    INNER JOIN
        movies AS m ON m.id = c1.movie_id
    INNER JOIN
        actors AS a1 ON a1.id = c1.actor_id
    INNER JOIN
        actors AS a2 ON a2.id = c2.actor_id
);
```

Now, if actor NAME1 participated on the same movie that actor NAME2 there will be rows with next values on the previous view:

```
(id_name1, name1, movie_id, movie_title, id_name2, name2)
(id_name2, name2, movie_id, movie_title, id_name1, name1)
```

In other words, the relation will appear twice, but this simplify next queries...

Now, based on your definition, **the 1º degrees of closeness** for actor "Kevin Bacon" (actors that worked with him) can be obtained like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_1_degree_to_kb AS (
    SELECT
        actor1_id, actor1_fullname
    FROM
        vw_relations
    WHERE
        actor2_fullname = "Kevin Bacon"
);
```

Now, for **the 2º degrees of closeness** for actor "Kevin Bacon" (actors that worked with actors that worked with him) i will do this (and save in a view too):

```
CREATE VIEW vw_2_degree_to_kb AS (
    SELECT
        actor1_id, actor1_fullname
    FROM
        vw_relations
    WHERE
        actor2_id IN (SELECT actor1_id FROM vw_1_degree_to_kb)
    AND
        actor1_id NOT IN (SELECT actor1_id FROM vw_1_degree_to_kb)
    AND
        actor1_fullname != "Kevin Bacon"
);
```

In others words, this view contains actors that worked with the 1º degree of closeness actors of "Kevin Bacon", but that not already belong to that set.

Even more, **the 3º degrees of closeness** will be like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_3_degree_to_kb AS (
    SELECT
        actor1_id, actor1_fullname
    FROM
        vw_relations
    WHERE
        actor2_id IN (SELECT actor1_id FROM vw_2_degree_to_kb)
    AND
        actor1_id NOT IN (SELECT actor1_id FROM vw_1_degree_to_kb)
    AND
        actor1_id NOT IN (SELECT actor1_id FROM vw_2_degree_to_kb)
    AND
        actor1_fullname != "Kevin Bacon"
);
```

Comment: the goal is to find those actors with 2 degrees of closeness to K. Bacon, i.e. not those who played in the same movies as him, but those who played in at least 1 movie together with actor(s) who themselves played in at least 1 movie with K.B.

Comment: I have added this goal to the answer, please update the answer with the tables structure too.

Comment: the tables are MOVIES with columns [id, title], ACTORS [id, full_name] and CAST [movie_id, actor_id] which connects the 2 other and gives all actors for all movies (sort of a full outer join).  The exercise, in the first section, needs to return those actors_id which have 2 degrees of closeness with Kevin Bacon (as in my initial post), and also in subsequent sections, those actors having respectively 3, 4, 5, .. degrees of closeness to him until all are encompassed. It gets very very messy from 3 degrees already, but I believe I am not approaching this wisely..

Comment: I did not found an easy way to get your goals, but i updated my answer with an implementation using views, hope this helps us.